# What is the best way to avoid duplication in my music Library database modeling using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling

As a newbie in mongodb, I tried to model a music library database. From what I have done so far, I suspect some level of duplications, especially with the artist entity. Suggestions on how to avoid such duplications or perfect the database model will be appreciated.

```
{
"track_id": "1",
"Duration": " 5.00",
"title": "Andersen",
"date released": ISODate("01-25-1896")
"Artist": 
    {
        "Name": "Lee Jones",
        "Gender": "Male"
    },

 "Album": 
    {
      "Name": "star wars",
      "date released": ISODate("01-25-1896")
      "Artist": 
            {
              "Name": "Lee Jones",
              "Gender": "Male"
            }
     }
```

}

In the above codes I made use of the Embedded document pattern considering the following:

1. A track is made by an artist
2. A artist can make zero to many tracks
3. A track can be associated with zero album or a single album
4. An album can have one or many tracks
5. An album belongs to an artist
6. An artist can own zero to many albums

Comment: Hi, a `Track` is made by one or many artist, so probably you want to use a Array of documents, theses document will hold artists's `name`, `_id`. Why do i need to know the artist's gender?

Answer (score 0):

> With MongoDB, how you model your data depends – entirely – on your
> particular application’s data access patterns. You want to structure
> your data to match the ways that your application queries and updates
> it.

Of course you can reference (link) the `Artist field` with a `Artist Document` and avoid data duplication, but this destroy the may purpose of a document database ( ease of development and fast response), you should favor embedding unless there is a compelling reason not to.

More info: [6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3)